# Spark JAVA Program

Tags: java, apache-spark, java-8

I am trying to solve this problem using Spark Java:

> Write some spark code which returns the number of trips for each
>   customerId. A trip is a sequence of travel transactions with no more
>   than 7 days in between each transaction.

Input: (customerid,fname,lname,gender,date)
Output: (customerid, numTrips)

The code I tried:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
TripData td=new TripData();
JavaRDD<String> getData= jsc.read().textFile("E:/PROJECTS/SPARK/RESOURCES/TRIPS_MOCK_DATA.txt").javaRDD();
JavaPairRDD<Integer,Iterable<Long>> tripByKey=  getData.mapToPair(line->
    {
        String[] parts=SPACES.split(line);
        return new Tuple2<>(Integer.parseInt(parts[0]),sdf.parse(parts[4]).getTime());
    }).groupByKey().sortByKey();
```

Solution:
I created a Map pair with CustomerId and list of dates, next I want to sort the dates and find the difference in dates to be less than 7 days.

I am new to Spark, not getting any hint to proceed further, could anyone please help me out?

Sample Input and Output:

[image: Sample]

Comment: share sample input expected output and also what you have tried so far...

Comment: given a sequence of transactions `t0, t1, t2, t3...tn`, there is actually more than one way of selecting a subsequence of transactions from it such that the interval between any two transactions would be less than 7 days. for example consider `1, 3, 7, 8, 13` . I may take `1, 7, 13` and `3, 7, 13` and `7, 8, 13` and some more. are you given a requirement to pick up the LONGEST subsequence?

Comment: @PrasadKhode ,Please find the screenshot above for sample input output

Comment: What happens with dates like this: 2018-01-01, 2018-01-08, 2018-01-09? There are 7 days between 1st and 8th and 1 day between 8th and 9th. Do they all form a single trip or do they form two trips?

Comment: @Simon,this combination forms two trips

Comment: I read that as 1 trip. Can you clarify which days are which trips from that example?

Comment: So a trip requires at least two transactions? And transactions on July 5, July 10 and July 15 would form 1 trip??

Comment: does this combination `2018-01-01, 2018-01-08, 2018-01-09` form two trips or three trips? `1->2`, `2->3`, `1->2->3`

Comment: Please let me know any approach to proceed with the problem

Comment: I humbly suggest that an approach to proceed with the problem would be to explain better, give clear answers to the question asked in the comments.

Comment: @OleV.V.  2018-01-01, 2018-01-08, 2018-01-09  form two trips

Answer (score 0):

```
JavaPairRDD<Integer,Iterable<Long>> tripByKey=  getData.mapToPair(line->
    {
        String[] parts=SPACES.split(line);
        return new Tuple2<>(Integer.parseInt(parts[0]),sdf.parse(parts[4]).getTime());
    }).groupByKey();
```

After groupByKey transformation,we will have user (key), all dates for that user( value as iterable).
Now to get the number of trips per user, we will have to sort these dates, and put our logic to get trips per user.

```
JavaPairRDD<Integer, Integer> tripsCountPerUser = tripByKey.mapValues(func);


 Function<Iterable<Long>, Integer> fun = (Iterable<Long> itr ) -> {
        List<Long> dates = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Long i:itr) {
            dates.add(i);
        }
        Collections.sort(dates);
        long day = 86400000l ;
        long days7 = day * 7;

        int count = 0;
        Long firstDay = null;
        for (Long dt : dates) {
            if(firstDay == null)
            {
                firstDay = dt;
                count = 1;
            }
            else {
                Long diffMs = dt - firstDay ;

                if(diffMs > days7 ) {
                    firstDay = dt;
                    count ++;
                }
            }
        }
        return count;
    };
```

The above code is not an optimised code can be done several different ways.
The above code is to give a way to solve the problem.
Hope it helps.

Assumption:-

2018-01-01, 2018-01-08, 2018-01-09, 2018-01-11 considers two trips which are,

1. 2018-01-01, 2018-01-08 (with in 7 days)
2. 2018-01-09, 2018-01-11 (7 days)